# Trying to detect word in array

Tags: php

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvuiq.png)First of all, I am new to programming and my code might be a mess. I want to detect a word from an array. I've searched the internet and I found in_array. This is my code:

Array of detectable words:

```
function randomWoord() {
    $woorden = array(
      'appel',
      'boom',
      'auto',
      'school',
      'tafel',
      'laptop',
      'huis',
      'zomer',);
```

Function trying to detect the word:

```
function isWoord($woord){
    if (in_array("appel", $woorden)) {
        echo "Found";
    }
  }
```

```
echo $spel->isWoord();
```

But when I do this I get this error:

Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function spel::isWoord(), 0 passed in /opt/lampp/htdocs/DG2/DG2Galgje/galgje.php on line 48 and exactly 1 expected in /opt/lampp/htdocs/DG2/DG2Galgje/galgje.php:32 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/DG2/DG2Galgje/galgje.php(48): spel->isWoord() #1 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/DG2/DG2Galgje/galgje.php on line 32

How can I fix this, thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you screenshot your code ? Or add it here?

Comment: I added it at the first line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can we see the `isWoord()` function ? The error is pretty explicit. This function wants an argument, and you are not giving any arguments to it.
By the way, if you are already `echo`ing something, you don't need to `echo` it two times. Here you use it in your `in_array` but also when calling `isWoord()`.

EDIT :

```php
$words = [
    'this',
    'is',
    'a',
    'list',
    'of',
    'words'
];

function isWoord($woord, $woorden){
    if (in_array($woord, $woorden)) {
        return "Found";
    }
}

isWoord('this', $words);
```

Comment: @Shikaziku I edited my original post. Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried your solution, but it says: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'isWoord' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/DG2/DG2Galgje/galgje.php on line 38 - maybe I did something wrong?

Comment: Please give me your entire php file. It's really hard when we only have few parts.

Comment: Here is what i did : https://pastebin.com/d2GKWA6V
Are we okay ?

Comment: You are welcome. You should check a little bit about POO. Have a nice learning path. See ya !

Answer (score 0):

yes, you searched correctly in_array() function is used to find a particular word from the array. It looks like error is in the isWord() function can you please show me isWord() Function.